# How can I find the RFC file that covers a particular topic?

Tags: linux, bash

I have downloaded, and installed the current RFC files via zypper, into /usr/share/doc/rfc/.
All my RFC files are gzipped.

When I want to find a particular topic, I use this command in my bashrc configuration file as function:

```
findrfc() {
  for file in /usr/share/doc/rfc/*.gz
  do 
    zcat $file|head -20|grep -i $* && stat -c "%n" $file
  done
}
```

However, this method is a way too time consuming.
Is there a more efficient way, or a program like the "apropos" command for man pages that would accomplish this task?

Comment: Please don't add "[Solved]" to your title. Once you can accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once again i am answering my own question

Ok the perl Script qdot suggested tries to find the words in the index file. i was  not aware of the existence of such file. Therefore:

```
rfcfind()
{
zgrep -i $* /usr/share/doc/rfc/rfc-index.txt.gz || echo "no subject found in rfc for $*"
}
```

is the command i was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try rfcutil?

I didn't use it myself, but that's what my packagemanager claims:

```
* app-text/rfcutil
     Available versions:  3.2.3 (~)3.2.3-r1
     Homepage:            http://www.dewn.com/rfc/
     Description:         return all related RFCs based upon a number or a search string
```

---

Update: yes, it works just fine.

```
valentha qdot # rfc -i
Modem users one moment, it's about 1024k (doesn't need to be updated often)
original lines  = 0     /var/cache/rfc/rfc-index
new lines       = 25078 /var/cache/rfc/rfc-index

valentha qdot # rfc -s Avian  
The Result:
1149 Standard for the transmission of IP datagrams on avian carriers.
     D. Waitzman. April 1 1990. (Format: TXT=3329 bytes) (Updated by
     RFC2549) (Status: EXPERIMENTAL)
2549 IP over Avian Carriers with Quality of Service. D. Waitzman.
     April 1 1999. (Format: TXT=9519 bytes) (Updates RFC1149) (Status:
     INFORMATIONAL)
```

Comment: Hahaha the April jokes :)

Comment: qdot: Thanks for this suggestion. So far i downloaded the perl script. but this does not work on my box. any other suggestions.